# Python Selenium on AngularJs site

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I am trying to automate reading my phone bill from the carrier website. www.fido.ca

However, the site is built with angularjs and I can't find the element using python and selenium webdriver. Please see below for the codes I've tried.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.fido.ca/pages/#/login?m=login'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='BC']")))
```

It returns selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Note: I can see the element from the front end, but no idea why webdriver can't see it.

Comment: It looks like you aren't logging in though. Or does the webdriver essentially get your current firefox session?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to bypass the region select modal pop up first. Stuck at that right now.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a page, you would see the overlay "Welcome to Fido!" screen which makes your desired element invisible - hence the timeout error.

Handle the screen by selecting a region and clicking "Continue" or "X" (close).

Comment: That is what I am trying to do by waiting to see the 'BC' element for me to select. But Python can't see that element. Don't know why.